# Htaccess regex expression to redirect URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I express the following redirect rule using Regex and htaccess:

From:

```
domain.com/***anything***/tag/***rest_of_URL
```

To:

```
domain.com/artigos/tag/***rest_of_URL
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(tag)/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Which is causing a redirection loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!artigos/)[^/]+/(tag/.*)$ /artigos/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: I get a redirection loop